# How to write a generic forwarding lambda in C++14?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, perfect-forwarding

How do I write a generic forwarding lambda in C++14?

#### Try #1

```
[](auto&& x) { return x; }
```

Inside the function body, `x` is an lvalue, so this doesn't work.

#### Try #2

```
[](auto&& x) { return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x); }
```

This properly forwards references inside the lambda, but it will always return *by value* (unless the compiler elides the copy).

#### Try #3

```
[](auto&& x) -> decltype(x) { return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x); }
```

This returns the same type as the argument (probably `-> auto&&` would work as well) and appears to work properly.

#### Try #4

```
[](auto&& x) noexcept -> decltype(x) { return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x); }
```

Does adding `noexcept` make this lambda more applicable and thus strictly better than #3?

Comment: The Try 1 is already enough. the compiler will move it for you if the type of data has a move constructor/move assignment defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A return type of `decltype(x)` is insufficient.

Local variables and function parameters taken by value can be implicitly moved into the return value, but not function parameters taken by rvalue reference (x is an lvalue, even though `decltype(x)` == rvalue reference if you pass an rvalue). The reasoning the committee gave is that they wanted to be certain that when the compiler implicitly moves, no one else could possibly have it. That is why we can move from a prvalue (a temporary, a non-reference qualified return value) and from function-local values. However, someone could do something silly like

```
std::string str = "Hello, world!";
f(std::move(str));
std::cout << str << '\n';
```

And the committee didn't want to silently invoke an unsafe move, figuring that they should start out more conservative with this new "move" feature. Note that in C++20, this issue will be resolved, and you can simply do `return x` and it will do the right thing. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0527r0.html

For a forwarding function, I would attempt to get the `noexcept` correct. It is easy here since we are just dealing with references (it is unconditionally `noexcept`). Otherwise, you break code that cares about `noexcept`.

This makes the final ideal forwarding lambda look as follows:

```
auto lambda = [](auto && x) noexcept -> auto && { return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x); };
```

A return type of `decltype(auto)` will do the same thing here, but `auto &&` better documents that this function always returns a reference. It also avoids mentioning the variable name again, which I suppose makes it slightly easier to rename the variable.

As of C++17, the forwarding lambda is also implicitly constexpr where possible.

Comment: clang doesn't have the bug you describe. If you actually instantiate the template function, it correctly diagnoses the error. But your `static_assert` only checks `compiles(0)`'s signature, and the error is not in the signature.

Comment: Actually, GCC doesn't have the bug either. Your example is correctly rejected by GCC if the function is actually instantiated too. There is a closely related bug, but not something that gets exposed by your test program.

Comment: Yeah there's no bug. The lambda compiles, you just can't call it with an rvalue reference (on either gcc or clang). I had only been checking return types so never actually instantiated the bodies.

Comment: I have closed the bug reports as invalid. Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 6):

Your first two tries don't work because return type deduction drops top-level cv-qualifiers and references, which makes generic forwarding impossible. Your third is exactly correct <s>just unnecessarily verbose, the cast is implicit in the return type</s>. And `noexcept` is unrelated to forwarding.

Here are a few more options worth throwing out for completeness:

```
auto v0 = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(x) { return x; };
auto v1 = [](auto&& x) -> auto&& { return x; };
auto v2 = [](auto&& x) -> auto&& { return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x); };
auto v3 = [](auto&& x) -> decltype(auto) { return std::forward<decltype(x)>(x); };
```

`v0` will compile and look as if it returns the correct type, but will fail at compilation if you call it with an rvalue reference due to the requested implicit conversion from lvalue reference (`x`) to rvalue reference (`decltype(x)`). This fails on both gcc and clang.

`v1` will always return an lvalue reference. If you call it with temporary, that gives you a dangling reference.

Both `v2` and `v3` are correct, generic forwarding lambdas. Thus, you have three options for your trailing return type (`decltype(auto)`, `auto&&`, or `decltype(x)`) and one option for the body of your lambda (a call to `std::forward`).

Comment: This is wrong. The OP is correct to point out in the question that this will fail: `x` as an expression is an lvalue, and cannot be used as the return expression if the return type is an rvalue reference. (Even though the expression `x` is an lvalue, `decltype(x)` can still be an rvalue reference type.)

Comment: @hvd OP didn't point this out, but yes. Serves me right for figuring if clang and gcc both do something it must b eright. Updated the answer with strikethroughs.

Comment: The OP put "Inside the function body, x is an lvalue, so this doesn't work." in the question, but admittedly not for the `-> decltype(x)` version, so yeah, that's a bit confusing. :) Anyway, clang does correctly reject it: `[](auto&& x) -> decltype(x) { return x; } (0);` fails with "error: rvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to lvalue of type 'int'". GCC does too: "error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'".

Comment: @hvd Huh. How did I test this then. I guess the answer is "badly"

Answer (score 2):

The fewest characters, yet fully featured, version I can generate is:

```
[](auto&&x)noexcept->auto&&{return decltype(x)(x);}
```

this uses an idiom I find useful -- when forwarding `auto&&` parameters in a lambda, do `decltype(arg)(arg)`.  Forwarding the `decltype` through `forward` is relatively pointless if you know that the arg is of reference type.

If `x` was of value type, `decltype(x)(x)` actually produces a copy of `x`, while `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)` produces an rvalue reference to `x`.  So the `decltype(x)(x)` pattern is less useful in the general case than `forward`: but this isn't the general case.

`auto&&` will allow references to be returned (matching the incoming references).  Sadly, reference lifetime extension won't work properly with the above code -- I find that forwarding rvalue references into rvalue references is often the wrong solution.

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type=typename Tag::type;
template<class T> struct R_t:tag<T>{};
template<class T> struct R_t<T&>:tag<T&>{};
template<class T> struct R_t<T&&>:tag<T>{};
template<class T>using R=type<R_t<T>>;

[](auto&&x)noexcept->R<decltype(x)>{return decltype(x)(x);}
```

gives you that behavior.  lvalue references become lvalue references, rvalue references become values.